# Xamarin.iOS Cant Deploy on Iphone

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I have a windows laptop and a mac mini my problem is that It wont deploy on iphone if I use Visual Studio Xamarin on windows to install my app, but it works fine with  Visual Studio For Mac.

Here's what I get after build succeded on Visual Studio Xamarin on windows :

```
1>------ Build started: Project: FinalCustomerApp.iOS, Configuration: Debug iPhone ------
1>  Connecting to Mac server 192.168.8.100...
1>  FinalCustomerApp.iOS -> C:\Users\Jeremy Paul\Desktop\FinalCustomerApp\FinalCustomerApp\FinalCustomerApp.iOS\bin\iPhone\Debug\FinalCustomerApp.iOS.exe
1>  Detected signing identity:
1>    Code Signing Key: "iPhone Developer: jeremypaulsf@gmail.com (ZJX84Z6W9F)" (C2CB3112B4E647AAF8249212D962865C9C7082D9)
1>    Provisioning Profile: "iOS Team Provisioning Profile: com.iPolaDroid04.FinalCustomerApp" (0d605a81-9fdb-49f2-a32b-e4a6cd070fe8)
1>    Bundle Id: com.iPolaDroid04.FinalCustomerApp
1>    App Id: LWPRWMFCS5.com.iPolaDroid04.FinalCustomerApp
1>  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/strip: removing global symbols from a final linked no longer supported.  Use -exported_symbols_list at link time when building: /Users/kidsministry/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/FinalCustomerApp.iOS/056a5cc10858d5a7e9fc8765158fef50/bin/iPhone/Debug/FinalCustomerApp.iOS.app/FinalCustomerApp.iOS
1>  bin/iPhone/Debug/FinalCustomerApp.iOS.app: valid on disk
1>  bin/iPhone/Debug/FinalCustomerApp.iOS.app: satisfies its Designated Requirement
1>  bin/iPhone/Debug/FinalCustomerApp.iOS.app: explicit requirement satisfied
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 1 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
Build started.
Build succeeded.
```

Any Answers will help thanks.

Comment: Can you provide more infomation ?Such as some error log about can't  install app on your device.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. My solution was to uninstalled and reinstalled both Visual Studio 2017 and Visual Studio for Mac.